# How to measure off diagonal elements of mixed state density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

Let’s assume I want to do quantum tomography using polarizers, half Waveplates and detectors , it’s obvious for me how we can measure diagonal elements of 2 qubit system density matrix using polarizer and detectors but I am confused how one can measure off diagonal elements of density matrix with linear polarizers half Waveplates and detectors .